# How to modify an assembly's version number after build?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have an assembly that is already built, but I need to modify it's version number. Is there a way to do this without recompiling?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398170/change-assembly-version-in-a-compiled-net-assembly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Assembly Version in a compiled .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398170/change-assembly-version-in-a-compiled-net-assembly)

Answer (score 1):

The assembly version number is held in more than one place. The one that's reported with the assembly's strong name is in the Assembly metadata table (ECMA-335 §22.2). However, the one associated with the `AssemblyVersionAttribute` that you can access through code is located as a parameterized constructor argument in the "blob" data section (ECMA-335 §23.3). Since the number in both locations is a fixed number of bytes, you could change it without recompiling. *However* you would break the signature if you are signing the assemblies, so this action would need to be performed before signing the assembly.