# Setting an executable's file version through C#/VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, fileversioninfo

I have an executable file which comes from an external source, and is always marked with version 1.0.0.0.
Unfortunately, I can't control the way it's compiled, and therefore can not set it's file version during compile-time.

What I want to do is write a simple console application that will modify the version automatically the moment a new version arrives, so that when I send it to the customer, file version will be correct.

I can't seem to find a way to do this after the file is compiled.
I don't care if File Version or Product Version is modified.
Any suggestions would be welcome.

EDIT: I've found this tool: http://www.codeguru.com/tools/standalonetools/article.php/c1403 That does what I need from command line.
It is nice but I rather do it from within code.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that file signed ? IF so, then you would make it unusable by modifiying it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Assembly Version in a compiled .NET assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398170/change-assembly-version-in-a-compiled-net-assembly)

Comment: The file I'm talking about is not a .NET assembly.
I'm not sure what kind of file it is, but probably a COM one.

Comment: Just open it in Visual Studio with File + Open + File and edit the unmanaged file version resource.

Comment: Hands - thanks for your comment, but it needs to be done problematically, not manually, as the whole process is automated.