# Set Version information for an existing .dll?

Tags: dll, version, versioning

Need To Set **Version** Information on the existing .dll

I need to add these to dll

**1.File Version
2.Product Version**

Tried [this free version](http://www.codeguru.com/tools/standalonetools/article.php/c1403).
does not work 
any Idea ?

Comment: Ok rahul i am trying this for you....please wait until done..

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool named [verpatch](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37133/Simple-Version-Resource-Tool-for-Windows) that does exactly that.
After you download it you can run it from command line as below:

```
verpatch your.dll /pv "product.version" /va "file.version"
```

There are many other flags that can be used to add extra information.
Try:

```
verpatch /?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **[Resource Tuner Console](http://www.heaventools.com/command-line_resource_editor.htm)** from Heaventools Software.

> Resource Tuner Console is a command-line tool that enables developers to automate editing of different resource types in large numbers of Windows 32- and 64-bit executable files.

See specifically the [Changing Version Variables And Updating The Version Information](http://www.heaventools.com/rtconsole-sample-script-update-version-info.htm) page for greater details.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a [tool](https://build.codeplex.com) for this purpose because didn't find anything that is enough easy to use and easy to automate. Developers find it useful.

I'm sorry if that might seem as a self-ad but I know how annoying is to sync versions...

Comment: Lacks vb.net support apparently.

Comment: The linked project "ProjectBuildCounter" does (according to its description) nothing with existing dll's what the question was about. BTW: codeplex is shutting down end of 2017