# c# Setting version of existing assembly

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, .net-assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Assembly Version in a compiled .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398170/change-assembly-version-in-a-compiled-net-assembly)

Is it possible at all in .NET to modify programmatically the version of **existing, already built assembly?**

Comment: I doubt it, as that might upset any other assemblys that reference a specific version of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398170/change-assembly-version-in-a-compiled-net-assembly

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31236/How-To-Update-Assembly-Version-Number-Automaticall Not sure if thats what you want though.